# Count number of distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserId, PoliticianId
FROM Votes
WHERE UserId= 1010
```

The result looks like this:

```
UserId | PoliticianId
1010     3
1010     10
1010     35
```

Is there a way to get number of rows returned by this query?
I've tried with COUNT(*) but it didn't work, probably because I've done the
query wrong.
I know I could just retrieve all the rows and count them on the server but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these rows have the same `UserId` but different `PoliticianId` so you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PoliticianId) AS result
FROM Votes
WHERE UserId = 1010 ;
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you. It seems that I have over complicated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(*) over ()` to display the number of rows returned.  This appears to be applied before `distinct`, so you'd have to move `distinct` to a subquery to get `count(*) over ()` after `distinct` is applied.

```
SELECT  UserId
,       PoliticianId
,       count(*) over ()
FROM    (
        select  distinct UserId
        ,       PoliticianId
        from    Votes
        where   UserId= 1010
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: This returns the value required, but it returns it in the same form as my result (3 column table), third column always being number 3, so this doesn't solve my problem. It returns 3 rows of 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you .

```
    select count(UserId) from (select UserId from Votes where UserId = 1010 group by UserId
, PoliticianId) result;
```

Comment: -1 There is no `from count_distinct` table, and no `ID` column.  And grouping by `user_id` when you filter on `user_id = 1010` can only return one row.

Comment: @Andomar , Column name edited . I just the sample query not exact one .